# How to expose Django-Constance settings via Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am building a project in which I need to have a few custom settings that are editable by certain users which do not have access to the django admin panel, who access the application via an Angular frontend.

I installed django-constance in order to have these custom settings editable, as it was the most recommended package I could find on the [Django packages site](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/). My problem now is that I do not know how to do to serve the settings on my API rest.

I started with some customized view:

```
class ConstanceSettingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

name = serializers.CharField()
value = serializers.Field()
defult_value = serializers.Field()
modified = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)


from constance import settings as constance_settings

class ConstanceView(APIView):

def get(self, request):

    settings = constance_settings.CONFIG.items()

    return Response(settings, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But now I dont know how to pass those settings correctly to my serializer. I tried this without success:

```
 settings_serializer = ConstanceSettingSerializer(settings)
 return Response(settings_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And I am only getting errors.

Some idea how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give you a demo

```
from .utils import get_settings
from constance import config
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet

class SettingViewSet(ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def setting(self, request, allow_settings):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # list all setting items
            return Response(data=get_settings(allow_settings))
        else:
            # change all allow setting items in allow_settings
            for key in request.data:
                if key in allow_settings and key in getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {}):
                    value = request.data[key]
                    setattr(config, key, '' if value is None else value)
            return Response(data=get_settings(allow_settings))

    def create(self, request):
        """
        <p>update with POST:<code>{'Key': new_value}</code>
        """
        allow_settings = [key for key, options in getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {}).items()]
        return self.setting(request, allow_settings)

    def list(self, request):
        """
        get all setting item
        """
        allow_settings = [key for key, options in getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {}).items()]
        return self.setting(request, allow_settings)
```

in utils.py:

```
def get_settings(allow_settings):
    setting_list = []
    for key, options in getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {}).items():
        if key in allow_settings:
            default, help_text = options[0], options[1]
            data = {'key': key,
                    'default': default,
                    'help_text': help_text,
                    'value': getattr(config, key)}
            setting_list.append(data)
    return setting_list
```

in urls.py:

```
router.register(r'setting', SettingViewSet, base_name='setting')
```

ask get `http://x.x.x.x/setting/` you can get:

```
[
    {
        "key": "staff_prefix",
        "default": "",
        "help_text": "工号固定代码",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "staff_suffix",
        "default": 3,
        "help_text": "工号尾缀",
        "value": "3"
    }
]
```

post `http://x.x.x.x/setting/` with data `{'staff_prefix': 'demo'}` you can update value in `staff_prefix`.

Comment: Hey! It works great for listing settings but it doesn't for updating them, I'm getting "the method POST is not allowed" when I try to update some setting. 
I didn't need the "username" part, as my settings are global

Comment: answer updated,but it's untested.you can test it yourself or wait me to test it tomorrow

Comment: I didnt quite understand what you wanted to do with this allow_settings, I guess it was a way to hardcode which settings could be changed and which shouldnt be. In my case, only the constance settings should be changed. I will mark this as correct as it worked for me to figure out how to do it. Thanks! :)

Comment: I adjust code to match your need,look the answer again

Comment: `django-constance` has a [get_values](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/blob/master/constance/admin.py#L83) method there on the admin module that gets all the values. Perhaps it is useful for someone to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer needs to know what to return. So for each field, you can do something like this:

```
class ConstanceSettingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    setting_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_setting_name(self):
        settings = constance_settings.CONFIG.items()
        # Retrieve your setting's value here and return
        return setting_value
```

That's on the way out. If you wanted to be able to change settings via PUT/POST/PATCH, you need to override create/update in your serializer and implement the logic to save the values yourself.

Another way could be to check how the storage of the settings is implemented. 
I have not used the constance settings so i cant say. But if it uses DB to store the settings, you can implement model serializer for the model which they use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same with a serializer if you using database backend:

serializer.py:

```py
from constance.backends.database.models import Constance
from constance import config
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import serializers


class ConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    default = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    help_text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    value = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Constance
        fields = ('key', 'default', 'help_text', 'value')

    def get_default(self, obj):
        default, _ = settings.CONSTANCE_CONFIG.get(obj.key)
        return default

    def get_help_text(self, obj):
        _, help_text = settings.CONSTANCE_CONFIG.get(obj.key)
        return help_text

    def get_value(self, obj):
        return getattr(config, obj.key, None)
```

views.py:

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from constance.backends.database.models import Constance

from myproject.apps.common.api.v1.serializers import ConfigSerializer


class ConfigAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ConfigSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Constance
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path

from myproject.apps.common.api.v1.views import ConfigAPIView


urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "config/",
        ConfigAPIView.as_view({"get": "list"}),
        name="config-list",
    ),
]
```